# Why when calling setTransform with a double value, the result is forced to int?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

According to [the specs of `setTransform`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/canvas.html#canvastransform), all the values in `setTransform(a,b,c,d,e,f)` can be "unrestricted double" value.

But when we first set the transformation with

```
_ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, -81662754.7269453, 0)
```

then

```
_ctx.getTransform()
```

returns

```
DOMMatrix {a: 1, b: 0, c: 0, d: 1, e: -81662752, 0}
```

```js
const _ctx = document.createElement('canvas').getContext('2d');
_ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, -81662754.7269453, 0)
console.log( _ctx.getTransform() )
```

It was set to a double but returned as an integer.

Why is it so?

Answer (score 0):

I'd say... browsers don't follow the specs and use "unrestricted floats" instead of "unrestricted double" here. 
Your value when stored as a Float32 would get rounded to that same `-81662752` value:

```js
const float32 = new Float32Array( [ -81662754.7269453 ] )[ 0 ];
const rounded = -81662752;

console.log( float32 );
console.log( float32 === rounded );
```

I did open [an issue on the HTML specs tracker](https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/5657), but don't give too much hope for a browser change.

Still note that you will face real issues in many places of the 2D context with values higher than 0xFFFFFF:

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

ctx.fillStyle = "green";
let v = 0xFFFFFE;
ctx.setTransform( 1, 0, 0, 1, -v, 0 );
// x -> 0xFFFFFE
ctx.fillRect( v, 0, 1, 25 );

ctx.fillStyle = "red";
// x -> 0xFFFFFF
ctx.fillRect( v + 1, 25, 1, 25 );

ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
// x -> 0x1000000
ctx.fillRect( v + 2, 50, 1, 25 );
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

And also note that this is a 2D context only issue, browsers do handle unrestricted double on other DOMMatrix objects:

```js
const mat = DOMMatrix.fromFloat64Array( new Float64Array([1, 0, 0, 1, -81662754.7269453, 0 ] ) );
console.log( mat );
```

---

Looking at the sources, it seems they do define it correctly:
[for FF](https://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/source/dom/canvas/CanvasRenderingContext2D.cpp#1795), and [for Chrome](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/master:third_party/blink/renderer/modules/canvas/canvas2d/base_rendering_context_2d.cc;l=541), but at least Chrome explicitly does

> ```
> // clamp to float to avoid float cast overflow when used as SkScalar
> ```

and I guess FF does the same somewhere else.

Comment: really heplful.

Comment: this situation is often encountered, when use canvas to render a map, and projection is web mecator.